# Adobe Air - Detect if connection is WIFI, 3G, or EDGE

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4

I need to determine which connection type a device is using. 
Distinguishing between WIFI and 3G doesn't seem to be a problem on iOS (using the [NetworkInfo ANE](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air/extensions/networkinfo.html)) and Android (using the native NetworkInfo class) but I've got no clue how to further distinguish between a fast (3G, 4G) and slow (EDGE) connection.
Is there a way to do this with Adobe Air?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Try this for detecting Mobile vs. Wifi on iOS. This requires the Adobe native extension "NetworkInfo"**

```
import com.adobe.nativeExtensions.Networkinfo.InterfaceAddress;
import com.adobe.nativeExtensions.Networkinfo.NetworkInfo;
import com.adobe.nativeExtensions.Networkinfo.NetworkInterface;

var vNetworkInterfaces:Object; 
if (flash.net.NetworkInfo.isSupported) 
{ 
  vNetworkInterfaces = getDefinitionByName('flash.net.NetworkInfo')['networkInfo']['findInterfaces'](); 
  mytrace("fall 1" );
} 
else 
{ 
  vNetworkInterfaces = getDefinitionByName('com.adobe.nativeExtensions.Networkinfo.NetworkInfo')['networkInfo']['findInterfaces']();
  mytrace("fall 2" );
} 

var hasWifi: Boolean = false;
var hasMobile: Boolean = false;

for each (var networkInterface:Object in vNetworkInterfaces) 
{ 
    if ( networkInterface.active && (networkInterface.name == "en0" || networkInterface.name == "en1") ) hasWifi = true;
    if ( networkInterface.active && (networkInterface.name == "pdp_ip0" || networkInterface.name == "pdp_ip1" || networkInterface.name == "pdp_ip2") ) hasMobile = true;

    mytrace( "active: " + networkInterface.active );
    mytrace( "displayName: " + networkInterface.displayName );
    mytrace( "name: " + networkInterface.name );
    mytrace( "hwAddress: " + networkInterface.hardwareAddress );
    mytrace( "--------------------" ); 
} 

mytrace( "has Mobile Internet: " + hasMobile );
mytrace( "has Wifi Internet: " + hasWifi );
```

Comment: That looks promising! Thank you very much for that! Any ideas if there's something similar for Android devices?

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if there's a solution a direct solution but when you're downloading a file you could check the speed at which file is downloaded, by using getTimer function in conjunction with loaded bytes and a ratio of total bytes.

Example

```
function init()
{
    startTime = getTimer();
    loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoaderInit);
    loader.load("some-site.com/myasset.png");
}

function onLoaderInit(e:ProgressEvent)
{
    $timePassed = (getTimer() - startTime) * 0.001; //it's in millisecounds convert to secounds
    $newBytes = loader.contentLoaderInfo.bytesLoaded - oldBytes; 
    var $rate:Number = $newBytes * $timePassed; //returns a value of bytes per sec.
    startTime = getTimer();
    oldBytes = loader.contentLoaderInfo.bytesLoaded;    
}
```

Comment: In theory, where the mobile connection is stable, you could do that, but given that even 3G networks are anything but stable (consider going under a bridge, or between tall buildings where 3G can likely drop to EDGE) you'd have to constantly download the file to check your connection speed. Not really practical. My workaround would be to completely drop my push mechanism on mobile networks and move to a polling. Not very nice, though as a stable 3G connection is plenty fast for data being pushed.

Answer (score 0):

Nice... if it works...  dunno if there's a solution a direct solution but when you're downloading a file you could check the speed at which file is downloaded, by using getTimer function in conjunction with loaded bytes and a ratio of total bytes