# Adobe Air - Detect if connection (i.e. WIFI, 3G, 4G) is active on any device

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe, flash-builder

I'd like to know how to determine any device is internet connected within an ActionScript 3 project.

I found a way to determine if an iOS device is connected using [Adobe's Native Extension](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air/extensions/networkinfo.html) by checking if an active NetworkInterface's name is "en0", "en1" (for WIFI connection) or "pdp_ip0", "pdp_ip1", "pdp_ip2"(data connection) from the [following stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872348/adobe-air-detect-if-connection-is-wifi-3g-or-edge).

However, how do I check other devices if they have an internet connection?

I think I can check if an Android device is connected by seeing of the active NetworkInterface name is wither "wifi" or "mobile" -- though I have not been able to confirm this.

How do I check the internet connection of other devices: i.e. desktops, Amazon, Fire, Nook, Playbook, etc?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried with NetworkInfo class?

like following snippet from AIR for Android by Veronique Brossiere

```
import flash.net.NetworkInfo;
import flash.net.NetworkInterface;
var network:NetworkInfo = NetworkInfo.networkInfo;
for each (var object:NetworkInterface in network.findInterfaces())
{
    trace(object.name, object.active);
}
```

best regards

Comment: yes, I am using the NetworkInfo class, but I am unsure how to determine if an active networkInterface which is connected to the Internet.
 
On my desktop with WIFI turned off, I get networkInterfaces that are active but they don't dictate if the computer is connected to the Internet: i.e. VMware Network

Comment: if you only want to know if the device has the internet connection than try to use air.net.URLMonitor

Comment: URLMonitor might actually work for my particular example. Thanks!                              However, I can foresee needing to know if the device is connected via WIFI versus 3G/4G. How do I go about doing that consistently across many Operating Systems? I think I am covered by checking the NetworkInterface names stated above of known wifi and data connections in iOS. I THINK the NetworkInterface names to look out for on Android are "wifi" and "mobile". Can anyone confirm if these assumptions are correct? What about other non-Android/iOS devices?

Comment: A disadvantage with URLMonitor vs NetworkInterface is that determining if there is an connection using URLMonitor isn't as immediate as when using NetworkInterface.